# Is it possible in C# to overload a generic cast operator in the following way?

Tags: c#, generics, casting, operator-overloading

Just wondering if there is anyway to represent the following code in C# 3.5:

```
public struct Foo<T> {

    public Foo(T item) {
        this.Item = item;
    }

    public T Item { get; set; }

    public static explicit operator Foo<U> ( Foo<T> a )
        where U : T {

        return new Foo<U>((U)a.Item)
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Conversion operators can't be generic. From the spec section 10.10, here's the format of a conversion-operator-declarator:

> ```
> conversion-operator-declarator:
>     implicit   operator   type   (   type   identifier   )
>     explicit   operator   type   (   type   identifier   )
> ```

Compare this with, say, a method-header:

> *method-header*:
>   *attributes<sub>opt</sub>* *method-modifiers<sub>opt</sub>* partial*<sub>opt</sub>* *return-type*
>   *member-name* *type-parameter-list<sub>opt</sub>* ( *formal-parameter-list<sub>opt</sub>* )
>   *type-parameter-constraints-clauses<sub>opt</sub>*

(Sorry about the formatting - not sure how to do it better.)

Note that the operator format doesn't include a type parameter list or type parameter constraints.

Comment: And even if we did support user-defined generic conversions, this one would still be illegal. It is illegal to define a conversion that replaces a built-in conversion. This would do so if T and U were the same type; you would be replacing the identity conversion.

Comment: As casts are decided by the compiler, if T and U were the same type, then it wouldn't use the user defined cast, and be leagal.

Answer (score 2):

Your code boils down to the line: `return new Foo<U>((U)a.Item)`

Where you try to assign a baseclass to an inherited class, which is impossible.

Let's say T (base-class) is of type `Stream` and U is of type `MemoryStream` (inherited class), you cannot assign a `Stream` to a variable of type `MemoryStream`.

Comment: Sure you can, If the reference masks the object as a Stream, but it is infact a MemoryStream, then you can certainly cast it to a Memory Stream. This is a legitimate method, the problem is that you can't actually specify generic constraints on an operator overload...

Comment: ...If you take the code I have and express it as a method rather than an operator overload it will compile

Answer (score 0):

I think the short answer is "Not possible. Try using a method instead"

Also seems to be dupe of this question
[Solution for overloaded operator constraint in .NET generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147646/solution-for-overloaded-operator-constraint-in-net-generics)