# Why can't I cast one instantiation of a generic type to another?

Tags: c#, generics, struct, casting

How can I implement a struct so that the following cast can be performed?

```
var a = new StatusedValue<double>(1, false);
var b = (StatusedValue<int>)a;
```

My implementation should behave similarly to `Nullable<T>`, which works fine. However, this code fails with `System.InvalidCastException`:

```
public struct StatusedValue<T>  where T : struct
{
    public StatusedValue(T value) : this(value, true)
    {

    }

    public StatusedValue(T value, bool isValid)
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.isValid = isValid;
    }

    private T value;
    private bool isValid;

    public static implicit operator StatusedValue<T>(T value)
    {
        return new StatusedValue<T>(value);
    }

    public static explicit operator T(StatusedValue<T> value)
    {
        return value.value;
    }
}
```

Result:

> Unable to cast object of type 'StatusedValue`1[System.Double]' to type
>   'StatusedValue`1[System.Int32]'.

Comment: Not really an answer, but maybe this (and the rest of that series) might be interesting for you: [Nullable micro-optimization, part four](http://ericlippert.com/2013/01/07/nullable-micro-optimization-part-four/)

Comment: Are you sure this code throws `InvalidCastException` ? I can't even compile this code.

Comment: Sorry, original code was a bit different, but the point remains the same

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025576/is-it-possible-in-c-sharp-to-overload-a-generic-cast-operator-in-the-following-w) with an answer from Jon Skeet and a comment from Eric Lippert (does it get better than that?!?)

Comment: What remains same? If original code is different you need to post code which mocks the original, not different one. If you post different code, answers also will be different.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, the question how to implement a struct to make the cast compilable and without throwing an exception.

Comment: To be honest, I wouldn't want to replace compile-time type-checking with run-time type-checking, so I'd just do `var b = new StatusedValue<int>((int)a.Value, false); `

Comment: This question doesn't really have anything to do with `Nullable`.

Comment: @JustinMorgan Nullable was chosen as a base implementation, because it works in desirable way.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This works for `Nullable<T>` types because they get special treatment from the compiler. This is called a "lifted conversion operator", and you cannot define your own.

From section 6.4.2 of [the C# Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx):

> 6.4.2 Lifted conversion operators
>
> Given a user-defined conversion operator that converts from a non-nullable value type S to a
> non-nullable value  type T, a lifted conversion operator exists that
> converts from S? to T?. This lifted conversion operator performs  an
> unwrapping from S? to S followed by the user-defined conversion from S
> to T followed by a wrapping from  T to T?, except that a null valued
> S? converts directly to a null valued T?. A lifted conversion operator
> has the same implicit or explicit classification as its underlying
> user-defined  conversion operator. The term “user-defined conversion”
> applies to the use of both user-defined and lifted  conversion
> operators

Answer (score 6):

If you're happy calling a method, try

```
public StatusedValue<U> CastValue<U>() where U : struct
{
    return new StatusedValue<U>((U)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(U)), isValid);
}
```

This will unfortunately throw at *runtime* rather than compile time if `T` cannot be converted to `U`.

**Edit:** As pointed out below, if you constrain to `IConvertible` as well as/instead of `struct` then every conversion is theoretically possible at compile time, and you'll only get a runtime failure because of bad runtime values.

Comment: Not sure but I think this will throw if T does not implement IConvertible even if an implicit or explicit cast exists between T and U. The good news is that you can constraint T to IConvertible

Comment: @InBetween Damn, I think you're right. I'd hoped it would at least try a runtime cast if given two reference types. Sounds like OP might only want to do it between the basic types anyway though.

Comment: Well it's already constrained to structs, so that's not so bad.

Answer (score 3):

Nullables are specially handled by the compiler, I don't know if this is the case here.

Your operators would allow this:

```
StatusedValue<int> b = (int)a;
```

which is probably not what you want, because `IsValid` is not copied this way.

You could implement an extension method like this:

```
 public static StatusedValue<TTarget> Cast<TSource, TTarget>(this StatusedValue<TSource> source)
    where TTarget : struct
    where TSource : struct
  {
    return new StatusedValue<TTarget>(
      (TTarget)Convert.ChangeType(
        source.Value, 
        typeof(TTarget)),
      source.IsValid);
  }


  b = a.Cast<int>();
```

But the compiler cannot check if the types are compatible. ChangeType also returns an object, thus boxing your value.

Comment: This won't build as the compiler doesn't know how to convert between `TSource` and `TTarget`. (Also because `Value` and `IsValid` don't exist...) And why an extension method when it's his own class?

Comment: I think you're right. Would need to cast (and box) to object before. Or better do a Convert. However, it was just an idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a casting, you can add a method like this:

```
    public StatusedValue<int> ConvertToStatusedInt() {
        return new StatusedValue<int>(Convert.ToInt32(value), isValid);
    }
```

As suggested in comment:

```
    public StatusedValue<Q> ConvertTo<Q>() where Q:struct {
        return new StatusedValue<Q>((Q)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(Q)), isValid);
    }
```

Comment: it would be indeed nice to have casting ability, because all basic types might be used as generic parameter.

Answer (score 1):

For a workaround, you will need to provide a way for converting from one underlying type to the other, since the compiler won't be able to figure that out:

```
public StatusedValue<TResult> To<TResult>(Func<T, TResult> convertFunc)
where TResult : struct {
   return new StatusedValue<TResult>(convertFunc(value), isValid);
}
```

You can then do:

```
var a = new StatusedValue<double>(1, false);
var b = a.To(Convert.ToInt32);
```

With some reflection you could build a lookup table of the `Convert` methods, and lookup the right one based on the type arguments, and then you could default the conversion function to `null` and if it's not provided, try to lookup the correct conversion automatically. This would remove the clumsy `Convert.ToInt32` part, and simply do `var b = a.To<int>();`

As Rawling points out, `Convert.ChangeType` can be used. This would make my method look like:

```
public StatusedValue<T2> To<T2>(Func<T, T2> convertFunc = null)
where T2 : struct {
   return new StatusedValue<T2>(
      convertFunc == null
         ? (T2)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T2))
         : convertFunc(value),
      isValid
   );
}
```

Comment: `With some reflection you could build a lookup table of the Convert methods` It's called `Convert.ChangeType`

Answer (score 1):

The answer to *why* it's like this has already been posted and marked as the answer.

However, you can simplify the syntax to make it easier and clearer to do this while retaining compile-time type-safety.

Firstly, write a helper class to avoid having to specify redundant type parameters:

```
public static class StatusedValue
{
    public static StatusedValue<T> Create<T>(T value, bool isValid = true) where T: struct
    {
        return new StatusedValue<T>(value, isValid);
    }
}
```

Next you need to expose the underlying value with a `Value` property (otherwise you can't cast it from code).

Finally you can change your original code from this:

```
var a = new StatusedValue<double>(1, false);
var b = (StatusedValue<int>)a;
```

To this:

```
var a = StatusedValue.Create(1.0, false);
var b = StatusedValue.Create((int)a.Value, false);
```

where you are doing a simple cast on `a.Value`.

Comment: He already has a constructor that does what your `Create` does.

Comment: @Gutblender But that constructor requires you to specify type arguments (i.e. you must put the type in `<LikeThis>`) whereas the static helper class allows the compiler to infer the type from the argument type. That's why I said "Firstly, write a helper class to avoid having to specify redundant type parameters"

Comment: True. I did notice the syntax is a bit sweeter. But the question becomes, can OP get away with a non-generic class that holds a `ValueType` instead? I have made a structure pretty much exactly like this for one purpose I had to describe mandatory and optional features. It works just fine for that.