# Operation with generic and double

Tags: c#, generics

I need to calculate in a generic class. I#ve found some solutions like here: [Solution for overloaded operator constraint in .NET generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147646/solution-for-overloaded-operator-constraint-in-net-generics), but i need to calucate T with double. is it possible to cast T to double?
So i can write code like this:

```
class Myclass<T>{
  T value;
  public double Half() {
    return  i.value  / 2;
  }
}

Myclass<int> i = new Myclass<int>();
double x = i.Half();
```

Thanks!

Comment: shouldn't that be `return this.value / 2;` in your sample code?

Answer (score 2):

Geenrics and operators don't mix. In 4.0 you can use `dynamic` for this; until then, [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) has `DivideInt32` which should work perfectly for cases like:

```
T half = Operator.DivideInt32(value, 2);
```

However, speciailizing in `double` won't really work well. You might as well *start* with `double` (instead of `T`) in that case. You could use `ToString` and `Parse`, but that isn't neither robust nor efficient.

Edit - there is also `Convert`, so you could *try*:

```
return Operator.Convert<T,double>(value) / 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer in the question you've linked to is correct: you can't really do this in C#.

The best you can do is to re-implement the `Half` method once for each possible type:

```
public double Half() {
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(double))
        return HalfDouble();
    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
        return HalfInt();
    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(decimal))
        return HalfDecimal();
    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could to is make the class constructor accept a parameter of type `Func<T,double>` that converts your `T` to a `double`. In the `double Half()` function, you call this functor and divide the result by 2.

For more information on this technique, read Bill Wagner's 'Effective C#'.