# C# generics constraint: must define an overloaded operator

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, operator-overloading, constraints

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Solution for overloaded operator constraint in .NET generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147646/solution-for-overloaded-operator-constraint-in-net-generics)
>   [Define a generic that implements the + operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598341/define-a-generic-that-implements-the-operator)

Hi,

So I have a generic class `MyClass<T>` and I want to put a constraint that the type `T` must define an operator, for example `public static T operator +(T x,T y)`.

Is that possible?

If not, I was thinking about implementing a runtime constraint using reflection. Is it possible to check if a class defines an operator like the one above using reflection? How?

Thanks, Malki.