# C# Addition between objects that are numbers

Tags: c#, object

I'm trying to find the best way to do following:

I have two Objects, object A and B. At some point in the program I know A and B are of type int, double or float. I would like to make an addition to them so A + B = C. C will be typed as we're used to while making addition between ints, floats, and doubles.

For example, if A was int and B float. Then C would be float.

Comment: You're asking for the *compile-time* type of C to depend on the *run-time* types of A and B?

Comment: maybe generic types can help. Can you show us what you have tried please?

Comment: Generics can't help, as you would need to constrain the types as `must have operator +`, [which can't be done in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598341/define-a-generic-that-implements-the-operator)

Comment: You should not be fighting against Strong Typisation. It is a important feature of .NET. Without it, we end up in the same problems as PHP or JavaScript programmres have: http://www.sandraandwoo.com/2015/12/24/0747-melodys-guide-to-programming-languages/ Do not fight it, embrace it. It is one of your strongest allies against bugs. Something with your whole design seems faulty if you can not even know the type of a variable. You should either pick one, or let teh user select one.

Comment: This question is indicative of a design flaw.  I think you should re-think your design.  You should never have to force a square peg into a round hole like you're doing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The closest you can come is:

```
dynamic a = ...;
dynamic b = ...;
dynamic c = a + b;
```

That will perform the appropriate kind of addition, but you won't know the type of the result until execution time.

Comment: It should also be noted that it utterly breaks types. A function is handed a dynamic, is prone to return a dynamic as well - regardless wich types were specificed. Think of it as the Dark Side: "If once you go this path, forever will it dominate your destiny".

Comment: I actually want to return Object. I know I could make a big switch on types of these methods and I could do all 27 cases how can I make an addition to three number objects. But that feels rather unclever.

Answer (score -1):

I dont know if i understood your question, but I think this can help:

```
Object objectA, objectB, objectC; 
float objectFloatC;
// Your business logic here 

if((objectA is int) && (objectB is float))
{
   objectFloatC = (float)ObjectC; 
}
```