# Is there a generic constraint I could use for the + operator?

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

is there some 'where' type contraints in can add to make the follwing code compile ?

```
public class Plus<T> : BinaryOperator<T> where T : ...
{
    public override T Evaluate(IContext<T> context)
    {
        return left.Evaluate(context) + right.Evaluate(context);
    }
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Actually, you can't. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147646/solution-for-overloaded-operator-constraint-in-net-generics

Comment: This is a frequently requested feature but it does not exist today; there's no way to genericize over the existence of a *static* method, and overloaded operators are always static.

Comment: To add to eric's statement go down the rabbit hole, operators don't have to just take T, they don't even have to return it! As such, despite really wanting it, I'd be happy to wait for it to be done right...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solution for overloaded operator constraint in .NET generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147646/solution-for-overloaded-operator-constraint-in-net-generics)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are no such devices in C#. A few options are available, though:

- in C# 4.0 and .NET 4.0 (or above), use `dynamic`, which supports `+` but offers no compile time checking
- in .NET 3.5 (or above), [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) offers an `Operator` class [which makes operators available as methods](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html) - again, without any compile-time checking

So either:

```
return (dynamic)left.Evaluate(context) + (dynamic)right.Evaluate(context);
```

or

```
return Operator.Add(left.Evaluate(context), right.Evaluate(context));
```

Comment: altough this does not use a type constraints this look more like the solution i'm looking for even if there is no compile time checking ;) thanks a lot.

Comment: If both approaches can be used, which is preferable and why?

Comment: Are any of these supported by Entity frameworK?

Comment: @Mvision no, they are not

Answer (score 8):

In C# 11 and .NET 7, there is a feature exactly for this (see [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/static-abstract-interface-methods)). It would have to go as follow:

```
public interface IAddable<T> where T : IAddable<T>
{
    static abstract T operator +(T left, T right);
}

public class Foo : IAddable<Foo>
{
    public static Foo operator +(Foo left, Foo right)
    {
        /* Something */
    }
}
```

Comment: Can T be int?  If not, is there a way to allow int?

Comment: @D.A. T can be `ìnt` but not with the example that I show. You would have to use built-in interface `IAdditionOperators<.,.,.>` in the `System.Numerics` namespace. I advise you to look into the other classes in this namespace because there is a lot of other interesting interfaces.

Answer (score 6):

The Type parameter constraints in C# are very limited and is [listed here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970%28VS.80%29.aspx). So the answer is no as far as compile time check goes.
If T is a type that you create and manage, one way to go about it would be to

```
interface IAddable 
{
   IAddable Add(IAddable foo);
}
```

and implement IFoo for all your types and use `where T: IAddable` as constraint and use `Add()` instead of `+`

Answer (score 3):

With [C# 8 default interface methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods) you can achieve something similar, but it might not solve your exact use case:

You can define an interface with a default implementation of an operator:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    double Value { get; }

    public static IFoo operator +(IFoo a, IFoo b)
    {
        return new Foo(a.Value + b.Value);
    }
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public double Value { get; }

    public Foo(double value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

And consume it in a generic method/class like this:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var f1 = new Foo(1);
        var f2 = new Foo(2);
        var sum = Add(f1, f2);
        Console.WriteLine(sum.Value);
    }

    public static IFoo Add<T>(T a, T b) where T : IFoo
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a generic constraints you can force `T`

- to be a reference type or a value type
- to inherit from a certain class
- to implement certain interface
- to have parameterless constructor

But that's all. You can't force the existence of the static `operator+` on it.