# C# generic operators - RTTI approach

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns, reflection, rtti

I intend to ask about generic operator+ overloading but not in typical "can I do operator+ for generic type" way.

**Questions are on the bottom**

I recently started to create matrix class in C# and after a while It came to me that I cannot do simple T + T !

Thus, I googled and googled and found several workarounds.

1. Create Expression [link](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/genericoperators.html)
2. Create abstract class `abstract class Matrix<T>{//some code}`. Create 'protected virtual method Add(T itemToAdd)'  and then create
   operator like this : `T operator+(T item1, T item2){return item1.Add(item2);}`(most posts on stack) and then inherit this method in `class Matrix : Matrix<int>`  [here](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/tree/master/src/Numerics/LinearAlgebra)
3. Use method Add such as : `T Add(T first, T second){ dynamic output = first + second; return output;}` (somewhere on stack)

First one just does not suited me so I tried second one but then I run onto serious problems like:

1. (A LOT of )repetative code - I created 4 classes for : int, double, long, Complex - my own type
2. Creating multiple extension methods and so on.

Third one is just so unsafe that I rejected it immidietlay.

After my struggling I came to realise : 'Why don't I use RTTI and reflection?' I know, it is expensive in running time but why not use static constructor to do this?

Here is my idea (pseudocode):

```
class Matrix<T>{
   static Func<T,T,T> Add;
   static Matrix
   {
     if(T is int) 
        Add = (first,second) = > ((int)first)+((int)second);
     else if(T is long) 
        Add = (first,second) = > ((long)first)+((long)second);
   // and so on for built-in types
   else
   { // T is not built-in type
     if(typeof(T).GetMethods().Contains("op_Addition"))
     {
       Add = (first,second) => typeof(T).getMethod("op_Addition").invoke(first,second);
     } 
   }
}
```

I know that reflection is costly but it will do it only one time (per type)!
And before you start argue : I am going to code `T is int` like this :

```
var type = typeof(T);
if(type==typeof(int)) // code
```

I am aware that I cannot explicitly convert T to int but there must be some sort of 'work around'. Problem is that (for example) Int32 has not explicit 'method' for operator+ hence, reflection is not of much use.

After all that introduction I have two questions :

1. Is it a good approach or do you see major flaws in it?
2. Is it doable? I don't want to start creating code without knowing for sure that my lambda function WILL work.

**EDIT 1+2**
I changed my code to generic.
I figured that maybe you need an usage of my class, here you are :

```
Matrix<int> matrix = new Matrix(1,1); // creates int-based matrix
Matrix<MyClass> matrix2 = new Matrix(1,1); // creates some other type matrix
```

**ANSWER**
based on dasblinkenlight's answer I managed to do this :

```
 public interface ITypeTratis<T>
    {
        T Add(T a, T b);
        T Mul(T a, T b);
        T Sub(T a, T b);
        T Div(T a, T b);
        bool Eq(T a, T b);
    }

    public class IntTypeTratis : ITypeTratis<int>
    {
        //code for int
    }
    public class DoubleTypeTratis : ITypeTratis<double>
    {
       //code for double
    }
internal class TypeTraits<T> : ITypeTratis<T>
{
    public Func<T, T, T> AddF;
    public Func<T, T, T> MulF;
    public Func<T, T, T> DivF;
    public Func<T, T, T> SubF;
    public Func<T, T, bool> EqF;
    public T Add(T a, T b) => AddF(a, b);

    public bool Eq(T a, T b) => EqF(a, b);

    public T Mul(T a, T b) => MulF(a, b);

    public T Sub(T a, T b) => SubF(a, b);

    public T Div(T a, T b) => DivF(a, b);
}
public class Matrix<T>
    { 
        private static IDictionary<Type, object> traitByType = new Dictionary<Type, object>()
        {
            {typeof (int), new IntTypeTratis()},
            {typeof (double), new DoubleTypeTratis()}
        };
        static Matrix()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Robie konstruktor dla " + typeof(T));
            var type = typeof(T);
            if (!traitByType.ContainsKey(type))
            {
                MethodInfo add, sub, mul, div, eq;
                if ((add = type.GetMethod("op_Addition")) == null)
                    throw new NotSupportedException("Addition is not implemented");
                if ((sub = type.GetMethod("op_Subtraction")) == null)
                    throw new NotSupportedException("Substraction is not implemented");
                if ((mul = type.GetMethod("op_Multiply")) == null)
                    throw new NotSupportedException("Multiply is not implemented");
                if ((div = type.GetMethod("op_Division")) == null)
                    throw new NotSupportedException("Division is not implemented");
                if ((eq = type.GetMethod("op_Equality")) == null)
                    throw new NotSupportedException("Equality is not implemented");
                var obj = new TypeTraits<T>
                {
                    AddF = (a, b) => (T)add.Invoke(null, new object[] { a, b }),
                    SubF = (a, b) => (T)sub.Invoke(null, new object[] { a, b }),
                    MulF = (a, b) => (T)mul.Invoke(null, new object[] { a, b }),
                    DivF = (a, b) => (T)div.Invoke(null, new object[] { a, b }),
                    EqF = (a, b) => (bool)eq.Invoke(null, new object[] { a, b })
                }; 
                traitByType[type] = obj;

            }
        }
}
```

And this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Feel free to ask any questions if there is anything not clear. It is not a homework of some sort - just me having fun with C# but I really want to create good code.

Comment: Are you doing this as an exercise or you just need Mathematical matrix operations for something else?

Comment: It seems to me like you could get this kind of functionality from some library around

Comment: I will probably create some LUP decompositions or calculating determinant in many ways or maybe even smith normal form but It always be only for fun not some serious calculations.

Comment: @EduardoWada, I am trying to build one myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your approach will work fine.

Your static constructor will run for each type parameter `T`, ensuring that `Add` is set correctly.

You may want to separate out the addition logic into a separate class outside your matrix, and use that class to run operations based on type for your matrix. For example, if you also need multiplication, you could build a `ITypeTraits<T>` interface that has `Add` and `Multiply`:

```
public interface ITypeTraits<T> {
    T Add(T a, T b);
    T Mul(T a, T b);
}
```

Now you can build implementations of `ITypeTraits<T>` for individual types, e.g.

```
public class IntTypeTraits : ITypeTraits<int> {
    public int Add(int a, int b) { return a+b; }
    public int Mul(int a, int b) { return a*b; }
}
public class LongTypeTraits : ITypeTraits<long> {
    public long Add(long a, long b) { return a+b; }
    public long Mul(long a, long b) { return a*b; }
}
... // and so on
```

make a dictionary out of them

```
static readonly IDictionary<Type,object> traitByType = new Dictionary<Type,object> {
    {typeof(int), new IntTypeTraits() }
,   {typeof(long), new LongTypeTraits() }
... // and so on
};
```

and get the one you need to perform operations:

```
ITypeTraits<T> traits = (ITypeTraits<T>)traitByType(typeof(T));
T first = ...
T second = ...
T sum = traits.Add(first, second);
T prod = traits.Mul(first, second);
```

Comment: I am very sorry, I forgot to add <T> in my code!
Will your answer be the same after this modification?

Comment: @Malin No, it would not be the same. Here is the approach that I used successfully in a project where I needed to do something like yours. I used classes in place of lambdas, and avoided conditionals and casts.

Comment: I wrote a very similar approach, but without the dictionary. Check it below.

Comment: Thank you @dasblinkenlight, this idea is briliant! It was exactly was I was looking for. Also : check my updated question I posted my code based on yours.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this natively in C# 11 / .NET 7 (or above):

```cs
class Matrix<T> where T : INumber<T> // or just IAdditionOperators<T,T,T>
{
    T x, y, z; // just to show we can do things
    public T Sum() => x + y + z;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with #3?  You can just check for type, like so:

```
public abstract class Matrix<T>
{
    public static HashSet<Type> AllowAdd = new HashSet<Type>
    {
        typeof(int),
        typeof(long),
        typeof(string),
        typeof(double),
    };

    public T Add<T>(T first, T second)
    {
        if(!AllowAdd.Contains(typeof(T)))
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Cannot preform addition for type: {0}", typeof(T).Name));
        }

        dynamic result = (dynamic)first + (dynamic)second;
        return (T)result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bulding on [dasblinkenlight's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34911469/41360), here's my version of it. The benefit is that it doesn't need a dictionary lookup, instead making the type system do it. Should be faster, I think, but I haven't measured it. Also a bit less typing.

```
public abstract class MatrixBase
{
    protected static class OperationDict<T>
    {
        private static Func<T,T,T> _notSupported = (a, b) => { throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("Type {0} not supported for Matrix operations!", typeof(T))); };

        public static Func<T, T, T> Add = _notSupported;
        public static Func<T, T, T> Multiply = _notSupported;
    }

    static MatrixBase()
    {
        OperationDict<int>.Add = (a, b) => a + b;
        OperationDict<int>.Multiply = (a, b) => a * b;

        OperationDict<decimal>.Add = (a, b) => a + b;
        OperationDict<decimal>.Multiply = (a, b) => a * b;

        // Etc. for all supported types

    }
}
public class Matrix<T> : MatrixBase
{
    public T DoAdd(T a, T b)
    {
        return OperationDict<T>.Add(a, b);
    }
}
```

Comment: He mentions building a library, a library's user would be required to change MatrixBase's implementation in order to use this code on his custom class that contains the + operator

Comment: @EduardoWada - Well, he can add an extension point where the user of the library can supply these functions. Also, if he can figure out a way to generate these functions, that too can be incorporated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right path, in order to avoid using reflection, you are required to somehow inform the compiler that you know "T" has the "+" operator, however, [this feature does not yet exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997107/is-there-a-generic-constraint-i-could-use-for-the-operator) in C#, so this is impossible to implement without runtime type checking or imposing other constraints.

If you don't care about the performance, you could use `dynamic`:

```
(dynamic)first + (dynamic)second
```

but that will take several reflection performance hits in every operation

Or you could use some other more complex approach that caches the specific methods in a dictionary, but you won't escape calling at least `.GetType()` in your `add`'s implementation