# How to avoid boxing/unboxing when using Generics in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, generics, dynamic, boxing

I want to make the following class to work with `int`, `double` and other additive types without run-time overhead on boxing/unboxing, but with possibility to reuse from another generic type:

```
public class agg<T>{
    public static T add(T a,T b){return a+b;} // compile error: Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'
    public static T add(T a,T b){return (dynamic)a+b;} // compiles, but involves boxing and unboxing at run-time
}
```

How can I achieve that ?

If I define method for each type explicitly, I can't use that class from another generic type `test<T>` without defining methods for each type explicitly in that class too:

```
public class agg<T>{
    //public static T add(T a,T b){return a+b;} // compile error: Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'
    //public static T add(T a,T b){return (dynamic)a+b;} // compiles, but involves boxing and unboxing at run-time
    public static int add(int a,int b){return a+b;} // won't be matched by test agg<T>.add(a,b) invokation
}
public class test<T>{
    public test(T a,T b){
        var c=agg<T>.add(a,b); //compile error: The best overloaded method match for 'agg<T>.add(int, int)' has some invalid arguments
    }
}
```

Comment: Why generics if it is just double and it? You could have two Add methods. double Add(double a, double b), and int Add(int a, int b).

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147646/solution-for-overloaded-operator-constraint-in-net-generics/147656#147656 which discusses exactly this problem with operators.

Comment: @Alexei: I see 4 things there: 1) reference to downloadable source code, 2) dynamic, 3) ICalc, 4) IL. #2 and #3 are not very good, #4 is interesting if it works, but I wondered more about pure C# solution. #1 - downloadable source code does a lot of things, I would like to have some simple example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution using pure C# (no [IL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6481274/195446) or [3rd party libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/147656/195446)):

```
internal class agginit{internal static bool started=false;}
public class agg<T>{
    //public static T add(T a,T b){return a+b;} // compile error: Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'
    //public static T add(T a,T b){return (dynamic)a+b;} // compiles, but involves boxing and unboxing at run-time
    //public static int add(int a,int b){return a+b;} // won't be matched by test agg<T>.add(a,b) invokation
    public static T add(T a,T b){return _add(a,b);}
    static Func<T,T,T> _add=null;
    public static void setAdd(Func<T,T,T> f){if(_add==null)_add=f;else throw new Exception("Can't init twice");}
    static agg(){
        if(!agginit.started){ // to prevent recursive actions
            agginit.started=true;
            agg<int>._add=(a,b)=>a+b;
            agg<double>._add=(a,b)=>a+b;
            // below we initialize all other potentially used additive types just for fun, if type is not listed here, it's not supported
            agg<string>._add=(a,b)=>a+b;
            agg<byte>._add=(a,b)=>{return (byte)(a+b);}; // dirty down-cast, needs to be enhanced with return type generic parameter
            agg<long>._add=(a,b)=>a+b;
            agg<System.Numerics.BigInteger>._add=(a,b)=>a+b;
            agg<StringBuilder>._add=(a,b)=>{var ret=new StringBuilder();ret.Append(a.ToString());ret.Append(b.ToString());return ret;};
            agg<IEnumerable<T>>._add=(a,b)=>a.Concat(b);
            agg<HashSet<T>>._add=(a,b)=>{var ret=new HashSet<T>(a);ret.UnionWith(b);return ret;};
            agg<SortedSet<T>>._add=(a,b)=>{var ret=new SortedSet<T>(a);ret.UnionWith(b);return ret;};
            agg<byte[]>._add=(a,b)=>{var ret=new byte[a.Length+b.Length];Buffer.BlockCopy(a,0,ret,0,a.Length);Buffer.BlockCopy(b,0,ret,a.Length,b.Length); return ret;};
            agg<System.IO.MemoryStream>._add=(a,b)=>{var ret=new System.IO.MemoryStream(new byte[a.Length+b.Length]);a.WriteTo(ret);b.WriteTo(ret);return ret;};
        }
    }
}
public class test<T>{
    public T res;
    public test(T a,T b){
        res=agg<T>.add(a,b);
    }
}
public class A{
    public int z;
    static A(){
        agg<A>.setAdd((a,b)=>new A{z=a.z+b.z}); // any class can define own add implementation
    }
    public void test(){
        var t1=agg<A>.add(new A{z=1},new A{z=2});
        if(t1.z!=3)throw new Exception("test failed");
        var t2=new test<A>(new A{z=1},new A{z=2});
        if(t2.res.z!=3)throw new Exception("test failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm, interesting approach. I like it. However, your `Func<T,T,T>` can simply be a property, instead of explicit getter (`add`) and setter (`setAdd`) methods. This has the benefit of allowing other code to see whether their `add` is null or not before trying to set it. In both cases, it's used the same simple way: `agg<T>.add(a, b)`. Here's that property: `public static Func<T,T,T> add { get { return _add; } set { if(_add==null)_add=value;else throw new Exception("Can't init twice"); } }`

Comment: @Tim: I agree, I added setAdd quickly just to demo that classes can register themselves to be additive without thinking a lot about design of it, so as classes test and A, naming, structure, e.t.c.

Comment: Excellent solution.  Just what I needed to implement type casting functionality to/from generic types.  Glad that I find a gem like this.  There are many questions on SO regarding how to cast a concrete type to a generic type and back, but no good solution that *avoids boxing*. This solution solves it nicely.  Basically change ``add`` to ``CastTo`` and the lambdas become ``x => x``.

Comment: Cool! There should be a compiler option to do this internally for a given method/class! Perhaps mark that `started` flag as `volatile`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll find a good way to do what you're trying to do. Some possibilities:

1. Use dynamic the way you show.
2. Have an if/else chain, or switch on full type name, to identify a list of known types as being equal to `T` (e.g. `if (typeof(T) == typeof(int)) add((int)a,(int)b);` etc.)
3. Instead of using `new test<int>`, create a `testInt : test<int>` class that calls the correct method.
4. Call the add methods using `dynamic` casting in `test<T>`, not in `agg<T>`.

Example of 3:

```
public static class agg{
    public static int add(int a,int b){return a+b;}
    public static byte add(byte a,byte b){return (byte)(a+b);}
    public static decimal add(decimal a,decimal b){return a+b;}
    // etc
}
public class testInt:test<int>
{
    public testInt(int a, int b) : base(a, b) { }
    protected override int add(int a, int b)
    {
        return agg.add(a, b);
    }
}
public abstract class test<T>{
    public test(T a,T b){
        T c = add(a, b);
    }
    protected abstract T add(T a, T b);
}
```

Example of 4:

```
public class test<T>{
    public test(T a,T b){
        T c = agg.add((dynamic)a, (dynamic)b);
    }
}
```

Why are you concerned with boxing/unboxing? Is this a highly performance-sensitive task? If so, anything involving dynamic is likely to be unfeasible. If you're not sure that this code needs to run as fast as possible, *don't prematurely optimize*: forget about performance for now and solve the problem in the best, most readable way you can.

Comment: I found better way than those 4 mentioned by you (see my answer) that does not involve casting, defining separate classes for each template type, or if statements for each type.

Comment: In certain application areas (e.g. embedded system drivers), things may be run within a tight loop every 10ms or so, and so the boxing objects do add up rapidly.  In my case, I once removed a substring operation and manipulate it char-by-char, and the program's runtime memory consumption dropped by 70% and CPU by half.  But of course, that function runs once every 10ms.

Comment: But I agree with you: don't prematurely optimize.